# Retrive image( long binary data) from Access Database and show in gridview in c#

Tags: c#

i am trying to retrieve image from access database which is saved as Binary Long Data . I want to show image in datagridview along side with other data.

[image in Datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4lPO.png)

```c#
String sql = "SELECT Config.ConfigID, Config.ProductName, Config.Features, Config.Price, Config.Picture, Stock.Quantity, Stock.TotalPrice FROM Config INNER JOIN Stock ON Config.ConfigID = Stock.ConfigID";
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                try
                {
                     while (rdr.Read() == true)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rdr[0], rdr[1], rdr[2], rdr[3], rdr[4], rdr[5], rdr[6]);


                }
                con.Close();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while (rdr.Read() == true)
{
  string path = @"c:\mytest.bmp";
  int pictureCol = 4; // the column #
  Byte[] b = new Byte[(rdr.GetBytes(pictureCol, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue))];
  rdr.GetBytes(pictureCol, 0, b, 0, b.Length);
  using(System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(path, 
              System.IO.FileMode.Create,System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
  {
      fs.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
  }

  dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rdr[0], rdr[1], rdr[2], rdr[3], rdr[4], rdr[5], rdr[6],
                                                 Bitmap.FromFile(path));
}
```

Comment: Not working brother , Please see the image attachment i added with that.

Comment: What is not working? `GetBytes` or `Bitmap.FromFile` ?

Comment: no, its saying , DestFilePath already in use by another program.